# C - Windows input redirection with getchar not working?

Tags: c, windows, redirect, getchar

I have this simple C program that reads characters from the standard input and displays a table with numbered rows and columns inside which are the characters we wrote.
The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define COLS 6
#define WIDTH 5

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

char buffer[COLS]={0};

int c;
int cols;
for(cols=0;cols<COLS && (c=getchar())!=EOF;cols++){
    buffer[cols]=c;
}
if(cols!=0){
    int a;
    printf("%-*s",WIDTH,"");
    for(a=0;a<cols;a++){
        (cols!=(a+1)) ? printf("%-*d",WIDTH,(a+1)) : printf("%-*d\n",WIDTH,(a+1));
    }
    printf("%-*d",WIDTH,1);
    for(a=0;a<cols;a++){
        (cols!=(a+1)) ? printf("%-*c",WIDTH,buffer[a]) : printf("%-*c\n",WIDTH,buffer[a]);
    }

    cols=0;
    int rows=2;
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF){
        if(cols==0){
            printf("%-*d%-*c",WIDTH,rows,WIDTH,c);
            cols++;
        }
        else{
            if(COLS!=(cols+1)){
                printf("%-*c%",WIDTH,c);
                cols++;
            }
            else{
                printf("%-*c\n",WIDTH,c);
                cols=0;
                rows++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("End-Of-File\n");
}
else{
    printf("No valid characters input\n");
}


return 0;
}
```

I compile the program with cc on Windows XP and if, in Windows console (cmd), I execute it with:

```
program.exe
```

then it reads the characters I input with the keyboard. It works fine.
The problem occurs when I decide that the characters are to be read from a txt file. So I create a txt file with notepad (in the same folder of program.exe) and I write a couple of sentences inside it. Then in console I execute:

```
program.exe<file.txt
```

but the output that I receive is "No valid characters input" as if the very first character read by the program was EOF.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

**SOLUTION:** I've just found out what the problem was. It was Comodo Internet Security that was preventing the program from reading characters from txt file. Actually Comodo was sandboxing the program. So after putting the program inside the "Safe Files" list everything worked like it should.
I hope this solution will help anyone with a similar problem.

Comment: i think you want to call
`program.exe 0<file.txt`

Comment: Same output as before.

Comment: The very first thing I would fix is the type for `c`, which is wrong. `getchar()` returns an `int`; not a `char`, and thats important if you hunt down what EOF is. `c` should likewise be `int`. I'd also fix your `argv` parameter to `main` which is wrong; it should be `char *argv[]`, not `char argv[]`.

Comment: @condorwasabi from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true), it looks like both of our commands _should_ work. Tested _sort_ command and redirects in both ways correctly..

Comment: Edited the question with solution. Thank you for your suggestions. I also updated the code as WhozCraig rightly pointed out.

Comment: @condorwasabi: You also can add the solution as an answer to your own question. And then have this answer marked as the accepted answer by clicking its check-makrk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SOLUTION**: I've just found out what the problem was. It was Comodo Internet Security that was preventing the program from reading characters from txt file. Actually Comodo was sandboxing the program. So after putting the program inside the "Safe Files" list everything worked like it should.